# Handling PySVN merges by manually

Tags: python, svn, conflict, pysvn

I'm using SVN as a backend for a collaborative framework. That said, I want to handle ALL the updates by hand, ie: no automerge, no auto-update.

so if updating brings the following changeset:
A file1
D file2
U file3
G file4

I want to process the update and the automerge by hand.

I know that this is possible in subversion CLI (for linux) by using the non-interactive flag or marking the file as binary but I didn't found this options in the pysvn.Client module.

Any thoughts about it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the prop of mime-type application/octet-stream.
This way svn would bypass the contextual merge feature.